# Why is initializing gl3w so much faster than initializing GLEW?

Tags: c, performance, opengl, glfw, glew

I'm using GLFW to set the OpenGL context and then test the speed of each library by initializing it multiple times, with all optimization flags on.

On my machine, **gl3w** can be initialized **100** times in about **0.5** seconds:

```
#include "gl3w.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    if (!glfwInit()) return 1;
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    GLFWwindow *win = glfwCreateWindow(960, 540, "Title", NULL, NULL);
    if (!win) return 2;
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(win);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) if (gl3wInit()) return 3;
    if (!gl3wIsSupported(3, 3)) return 4;

    glfwDestroyWindow(win);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

While initializing **GLEW** **100** times takes about **2.5** seconds, making it about **5** times slower!

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    if (!glfwInit()) return 1;
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    GLFWwindow *win = glfwCreateWindow(960, 540, "Title", NULL, NULL);
    if (!win) return 2;
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(win);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) if (glewInit()) return 3;

    glfwDestroyWindow(win);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

I am very surprised about this since both of these libraries are designed to fit the same purpose. Could someone explain what the difference is all about?

By the way, omitting the `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;` cuts time to **0.3** seconds, but then GLEW isn't initializing correctly because `glBindVertexArray(0);` just afterwards throws a segmentation fault while it shouldn't.

Comment: But, but, but! I thought jet-engines are faster than piston-engines. How come it takes longer to start and stop my jet engine than it takes to start and stop the engine in my car? I thought jet engines spin faster? This is essentially the question you've asked. Basically, start-up/run-down time have nothing to do with the speed reached during operation. I fail to see what this question actually aims to achieve.

Comment: @enhzflep Are you saying that `gl3w` makes all OpenGL function calls slower? AFAIK there's no difference! Or are you saying that GLEW does more than `gl3w`? I don't understand your jet-engine and piston-engine analogy.

Comment: No. I am saying that you report that GL3W is slower than GLEW, yet you make no attempt to conduct any test that supports such a claim. You merely measure start-up time. The point of the analogy was to demonstrate the ridiculousness of timing start-up time as a means of determining operating speed. ;)

Comment: That's what I am asking for. Why is initializing gl3w takes less time than initializing GLEW. Maybe I just worded it incorrectly. Edit: fixed the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because GLEW is doing more work than GL3W.

GL3W consists of *only* the functions from the OpenGL header `glcorearb.h`. This contains the functions in OpenGL 4.5, as well as many ARB extensions. This means it does not include other extension functions or non-core profile stuff.

GLEW gives you every function in the OpenGL registry. Also, there's this:

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
```

Normally, GLEW will check to see if a particular extension is supported before trying to load its functions. By using that, you're telling GLEW not to do that check. Instead, it will try to load every function regardless of whether the extension is specified or not.

You may have been told that you *have* to use this switch. That's not true anymore.

See, OpenGL 3.0 changed how you test extensions in OpenGL. And thus, the old method was deprecated, and thus removed in 3.1 and core profile 3.2+.

However, GLEW kept using the old extension testing functionality. As such, you had to use that switch if you wanted to use GLEW with a core profile.

GLEW 2.0, *eight years later*, finally fixed this... long after about a half dozen much better [OpenGL loading libraries](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) solved the problem many times over. But in any case, the point is that you shouldn't use this switch with GLEW 2.0.

Comment: Wow, it's so recent! No wonder it's not included in my Ubuntu repositories. Since I am using the core context anyway, I think gl3w will be enough for me. Thanks for satisfying my curiosity!